# Flash message is not displayed but exist in the flash profiler

Tags: symfony, twig, flash-message

I have a question about flash messages (I am using symfony 3.2),

my scenario is:

a user registrate then he will be redirected to login page with message :account created please check your email.

but no message is displayed ,but I can see it in the flash section in the profiler.

**my function**

```
  public function registrationAction(Request $request)
    {
    //my code
 $message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
                ->setSubject($subject)
                ->setFrom($this->container->getParameter('mailer_user'))
                ->setTo($email)
                ->setBody(
                $this->renderView(
                    'PepsBundle:Register:registerconf.html.twig', array('id' => $Id,'confirmationToken' => $confirmationToken,'name' => $name,'lastname' => $lastname)), 'text/html');

            $this->get('mailer')->send($message);



            $this->addFlash('success', 'Account created!');
           return $this->redirectToRoute('peps_login');
        }
```

**in my login.twig.html**

```
{% set flashbag_notices = app.session.flashBag('success') %}
```

**my profiler**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just assigning the array of messages to a variable called flashbag_notices

You need to do something like this to render the message

```
{% for messages in app.session.flashbag.all() %}
      {% for message in messages %}
            <div>
                {{ message }}
            </div>
      {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```